# Stacked Bar chart fixed width bar chart issue - Chartjs

Tags: javascript, c#, charts, chart.js

I am using chartjs Version: 2.1.4 to creating Chart in MVC C# application. I am using `"barPercentage: 0.2"`to control the width of Bar charts for fixed width settings. Its working fine in case of Only bar charts, But in case of "stacked bar chart" i'm unable to fix the width of bars. I am using following code to stacked bar chart as:

```
scales:
    {
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        // Change here
                        barPercentage: 0.2
                    }]
                }
```

In this case "barpercentage" property is not working. Please suggest me solution if any in "chartjs Version: 2.1.4".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `barPercentage` with `categoryPercentage` and fiddle with its value until you get what you want. When you have a stacked bar chart, you get one bar per category, so I guess this is the reason `barPercentage` is ignored, while `categoryPercentage` works fine.

Comment: O Thanks @xnakos it's working fine now.... Your guess is true.... barPercentage  is not working in stacked bar chart.... Using categoryPercentage  its working fine...
Thanks a lot Bro....